# frame won't repaint after adjusting string

Tags: java, arrays, swing, actionlistener, repaint

I am not sure what I am doing wrong to get my frame to change when I have the user input data and press enter to adjust the string that was set to display on the frame. I am just going to include the code that I feel is applicable since the whole code is pretty long, but if someone would like to see more of something, let me know and I can post more. Thank you for the help!

```
     //adds the Flower data to the Array and list
 ActionListener flowerAddAction = new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent flowerAddAction){
        if(flowerAddAction.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")){
            Name = NameTxt2.getText();
            Colors = ColorTxt2.getText();
            Smell = SmellTxt.getText(); 
            ID = (int) IDCmbo.getSelectedItem();
            if(((String) ThornCmbo.getSelectedItem()).equals("Yes"))
                Thorns = true; 
            else
                Thorns = false;
            plants[count] = new Flower(Name, ID, Colors, Smell, Thorns);
            displayEntered.setText(displayArray);
            count++;
            frame.repaint();
            frameB.setVisible(false);
        }
        }
};
 enterFlrData.addActionListener(flowerAddAction);
```

this code above is to add the action to when the user presses enter after inputting data into the textFields and ComboBoxes. Below creates a long string of an array that is created by the input. (If anyone has a better way of displaying an array on a JLabel I'd love to know because I know this is a little sloppy.

```
    //create a string of all values for the array
    displayArray = " ";
    String displayArraytemp = " ";
    for(int n = 0; n < 25; n++){
        if(plants[n] != null){
            if(plants[n] instanceof Flower){
                displayArraytemp = (n + ": " + plants[n].getID() + ", " + plants[n].getName() + ", " + ((Flower)plants[n]).getColor() + ", " + ((Flower)plants[n]).getSmell() + ", Thorny: " + ((Flower)plants[n]).getThorns() + "/n");
                }
                else if(plants[n] instanceof Fungus){
                displayArraytemp = (n + ": " + plants[n].getID() + ", " + plants[n].getName() + ", " + ((Fungus)plants[n]).getColor() + ", Poisonous: " + ((Fungus)plants[n]).getPoisonous() + "/n");
                }
                else if(plants[n] instanceof Weed){
                displayArraytemp = (n + ": " + plants[n].getID() + ", " + plants[n].getName() + ", " + ((Weed)plants[n]).getColor() + ", Edible: " + ((Weed)plants[n]).getEdible() + ", Medicinal: " + ((Weed)plants[n]).getMedicinal() + ", Poisonous: " + ((Weed)plants[n]).getPoisonous() + "/n");
                }
                else if(plants[n] instanceof Herb){
                displayArraytemp = (n + ": " + plants[n].getID() + ", " + plants[n].getName() + ", " + ((Herb)plants[n]).getColor() + ", " + ((Herb)plants[n]).getFlavor() + ", Medicinal: " + ((Herb)plants[n]).getMedicinal() + ", Poisonous: " + ((Herb)plants[n]).getSeasonal() + "/n");
                }
            displayArray += (displayArraytemp + "/n");
        }
    }
```

Below is showing the rest creating the label and includes the main method.

```
    final JPanel p2Base = new JPanel();
    displayEntered = new JLabel(displayArray);
     //entire constant GUI put together
p2Base.setLayout(new BorderLayout(10,10));
p2Base.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
p2Base.add(p1Right, BorderLayout.EAST);
p2Base.add(displayEntered, BorderLayout.WEST);

        public static void main(String[] args) {
    frame = new GUI();
    frame.setTitle("Plant Database");
    frame.setSize(900,700);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. After searching for a while I realized my issue was that I needed to declare and set the string inside the actionPerformed for it to be able to see. I ended up making the text a StringBuilder and used <html> and <br> to make the new text enter on new lines (which I'm sure is not the best way, but it worked). What I am caught up on now is all of the data will display, but it will display the first, then the 1st and 2nd entry. So, I need to get rid of the first so I don't display duplicates. Anyone have input on how to repaint? What I've tried hasn't worked.

Comment: *"What I've tried hasn't worked."*  What you've posted is not an SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

This looks suspicious to me:

```
flowerAddAction.getActionCommand().equals("Enter")
```

If you want this ActionListener respond to pressing the enter button then this will fail since the actionCommand String will not be "Enter". I'm not even sure what it will be, and don't really care, since I usually use ActionListener's for each component and so usually don't test the actionCommand String.

As for your messy array code, consider instead giving your flowers a decent `toString()` method or method of a similar idea that returns a useful String that can be displayed. That way you can get rid of all of those instanceof operations and have much simpler smaller code.

---

**Edit**

I should just shut up and read the API. The action command of a JTextField is the text it contains, unless you set it explicitly.

```
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class EnterActionCommand {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      JTextField field1 = new JTextField(10);
      JTextField field2 = new JTextField(10);

      // **** set the action command explicitly for field2 ****
      field2.setActionCommand("Field 2");

      ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {

         @Override
         public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.printf("action command: \"%s\"%n", e.getActionCommand());
         }
      };

      field1.addActionListener(actionListener);
      field2.addActionListener(actionListener);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.add(new JLabel("Field 1:"));
      panel.add(field1);
      panel.add(new JLabel("Field 2:"));
      panel.add(field2);

      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, panel);
   }
}
```